# JS - Is it possible to check if a variable is an object?

Tags: javascript, web

I'm trying to check if a variable is an object like so:

```
if(obj && typeof obj === Object) {
    console.log('obj is an object and does not return null value');
}
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

typeof returns a string representation of the type, but if you want to check for null then

```
if(typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null) {
    console.log('obj is an object and does not return null value');
}
```

Comment: @Jonatan Shahar: why using typeof and check for null. Best practice is using instanceof: From this book: http://books.google.com.vn/books?id=bHhlCrvbqSoC&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=maintainable+javascript+detect+Reference+Values&source=bl&ots=sBlLFhNWTU&sig=oGoonNrDxvTqvodk9-DP9LOUpFg&hl=vi&sa=X&ei=dIHSUdrVIuSXiAee6oG4Cw&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=maintainable%20javascript%20detect%20Reference%20Values&f=false

Comment: Note that this will return `true` for `Array`s too. If you want a strict check that it's an `Object` you can use `'[object Object]' == Object.prototype.toString.call(o)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, just replace Object with "object" string :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be;

```
typeof obj === 'object'
```

The `typeof` operator uses strings as identifiers. You can read more about it [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Answer (score 0):

```
'[object Object]' == Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do it is using `instanceOf`, [best practice](http://books.google.com.vn/books?id=bHhlCrvbqSoC&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=maintainable%20javascript%20detect%20Reference%20Values&source=bl&ots=sBlLFhNWTU&sig=oGoonNrDxvTqvodk9-DP9LOUpFg&hl=vi&sa=X&ei=dIHSUdrVIuSXiAee6oG4Cw&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=maintainable%20javascript%20detect%20Reference%20Values&f=false)

```
if(obj instanceof Object) {
    console.log('obj is an object and does not return null value');
}
```